# How do I use RegExp to search value of var for specific word

Tags: javascript

This was my code which it's not working. What I'm trying to accomplish is that if user doesn't type https://www. then automatically add it for them. If user does add https://www. then don't add it for them.

Javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var search = document.getElementById("search");
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
if (search.value !== "https://www.") {
    window.open("https://www." + search.value);
} else if (search.value == "https://www.") {
    window.open(search.value);
}
})
```

HTML

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="URL" 
autocomplete="https://www.">
<button id="button">Search</button>
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/aL4kr8hw/

Comment: if you add the full url and include "https://" then you won't be able to open the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var search = document.getElementById("search");

var protocol = /^(http(s)?(:\/\/))?(www\.)?/gi;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!search.value.match(protocol)[0]) {
   window.open("https://www." + search.value);
  } else if (search.value.match(protocol)[0]) {
    window.open(search.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="URL" autocomplete="https://www.">
<button id="button">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably accomplish this with the `indexOf()` function.

```
var searchValue = 'example.com';
if (searchValue.indexOf('https://www') > -1) {
   window.open("https://www." + searchValue);
} else {
   window.open(searchValue);
}
```